# Active/ Active SQL Server Clustering on AWS

Tags: sql-server, clustering, aws

I need to design and implement a highly available SQL Server 2012 clustering on Amazon AWS. In the white paper presented by Amazon, they provided an example of Active/ Passive SQL Cluster. Do you know whether Active/ Active is also possible?

Thanks

Comment: Active/Active refers to essentially two clusters running over two nodes.  Since cloud services are just standard machines like the ones you might run in your own datacenter, you should be able to run active/active.  Having said that, I would look at running an Availability Group instead of just clustering.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "Active/Active".  For standard SQL/Windows failover clustering, this terminology is a [misnomer](http://www.sqlha.com/2012/01/09/once-more-with-feeling-stop-using-activepassive-and-activeactive/).  You can certainly set up clustering using AWS, you just have to design it properly.

Comment: @Abiete : are you want to "loophole" environment or Hyper-V environment.

Answer (score 1):

Active/Active denotes two live datastores that can be simultaneously accessed by the application(s) in question.  SQL Server does not have a solution for this, including AlwaysOn Availability Groups, which at best will only provide you with additional readable replicas.  Outside of Oracle RAC, there isn't a solution for this.